# csv.Dictwriter text output not parsed correctly in Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am using csv.DictWriter to output a list of dictionaries for use in Excel. Narrowed down to just one key/value pair, it looks like this:

```
from csv import DictWriter

results = [{'symbol': '00287Y10',
            {'symbol': '03073E10'},
            {'symbol': '03783310'}]

with open('results.csv','wb') as outfile:
    ordered_fieldnames = ['symbol']
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, dialect='excel', fieldnames=ordered_fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(results)
```

The problem is that excel is not interpreting as text. The all numeric is converted to a number and the symbol ending in E10 is being parsed as scientific notation:

```
symbol
00287Y10
   3.07E+13
    3783310
```

So my understanding from other posts is that you cannot direct specific number formatting in excel from within the csv library, but is there any workaround so that Excel parses symbol uniformly as a text field? I would like to do this without changing the field's value for search purposes. Also please note I have tried using different delimiters and quote levels instead of the excel dialect but see no change in the output. Thanks!

Comment: No, this is something you need to fix in Excel. The CSV format is not up to that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Excel's Text Import Wizard, accessible at:

1. (in 2007 onwards) Data tab > Get External Data > From Text
2. (pre-2007) Data menu > Import External Data > Import Data

This allows you, in step 3, to specify a type for each column in the file, and setting this to Text rather than General avoids your issue.

Comment: That is not what I see. What exactly is in your *.csv file? It appears to already be converted to engineering notation.

Comment: Thank you! Excel was automatically converting on open. This is a good solution. I will open a blank worksheet and then run the text import wizard, where I can specify the column.